# Remove Redundant Values in Cell built from LISTAGG, Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I'm very new to querying in oracle. I have built an oracle query using **LISTAGG** like so:

```
select a.field1, 
LISTAGG(d.field2, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d.field2) AS FIELD_ALIAS
from
table1 a,  table2 b, 
table4 c, table5 d

where
a.field2 = b.field2
and
b.field2 = c.field2
and
c.field3 = d.field3

group by
a.field1
```

which returns:

```
field1   field2
----------------
504482   Labour;Labour;Labour;Labour;Labour;Labour;Labour;Labour
```

What I would like to do it simplify the second field and remove the redundant values so that I get:

```
field1   field2
----------------
504482   Labour
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that `listagg()` takes the `distinct` keyword.  One approach is to use a subquery:

```
select field1, LISTAGG(d.field2, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY field2)
from (select distinct a.field1, d.field2
      from table1 a join
           table2 b
           on a.field2 = b.field2 join
           table4 c
           on b.field2 = c.field2 join
           table5 d
           on c.field3 = d.field3
      ) t
group by field1
```